# How to search within a nodeset and delete a node from that same nodeset

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
        <w:body>
            <w:p w14:paraId="56037BEC" w14:textId="1188FA30" w:rsidR="001665B3" w:rsidRDefault="008B4AC6">
                <w:r>
                    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is the story of a man who </w:t>
                </w:r>
                <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-09-28T09:15:00Z" w:id="0">
                    <w:r w:rsidR="003566BF">
                        <w:t>went</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:ins>
                <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-09-28T09:15:00Z" w:id="1">
                    <w:r w:rsidDel="003566BF">
                        <w:delText>goes</w:delText>
                    </w:r>
                </w:del>
...
```

I use Nokogiri  to parse the xml as follows:

```
zip = Zip::File.open("test.docx")
doc = zip.find_entry("word/document.xml")
file = Nokogiri::XML.parse(doc.get_input_stream)
```

I have a 'deletions' nodeset that contains all of the w:del elements:

```
@deletions = file.xpath("//w:del")
```

I search inside of this nodeset to see if an element exists as follows:

```
 my_node_set = @deletions.search("//w:del[@w:id='1']" && "//w:del/w:r[@w:rsidDel='003566BF']")
```

If it exists I want to remove it from the deletions nodeset. I do this with the following:

```
deletions.delete(my_node_set.first)
```

Which seems to work as no errors are returned and it displays the deleted nodeset in the terminal.

However, when I check my @deletions nodeset it seems the item is still there:

```
@deletions.search("//w:del[@w:id='1']" && "//w:del/w:r[@w:rsidDel='003566BF']")
```

I'm just getting my head around Nokogiri so I'm obviously not searching for the element properly inside of my @deletions nodeset and am instead searching the entire document.

How can I search inside of  the @deletions nodeset for the element and then delete it from the nodeset?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need a syntactically correct XML sample that is the minimal necessary to demonstrate the problem. I'd recommend removing the namespaces too as they're not really germane to the question.

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want to selectively delete from the NodeSet. NodeSets are like arrays of pointers to the nodes in the document. Delete a node from the array and really all you're doing is lopping off that particular branch from the tree, in other words, you're removing that tag from the document. If you are gathering a bunch of nodes then want to delete only one, then search for only that one initially and delete it. Don't waste time and memory gathering the NodeSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"><p>foo</p></div>
    <div id="bar"><p>bar</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT
```

`divs` contains the `div` tags, which are a NodeSet:

```
divs = doc.css('div')
divs.class  # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

And contains:

```
divs.to_html # => "<div id=\"foo\"><p>foo</p></div><div id=\"bar\"><p>bar</p></div>"
```

You can search a NodeSet using `at` to find the first match:

```
divs.at('#foo').to_html # => "<div id=\"foo\"><p>foo</p></div>"
```

And you can easily remove it:

```
divs.at('#foo').remove
```

Which removes it from the document itself:

```
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     
# >>     <div id="bar"><p>bar</p></div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

It *doesn't* delete it from the NodeSet, but we don't care about that, the NodeSet is just a pointer to the nodes in the document itself used to give a list of what to delete.

If you then want an updated NodeSet after deleting certain nodes, rescan the document and rebuild the NodeSet:

```
divs = doc.css('div')
divs.to_html # => "<div id=\"bar\"><p>bar</p></div>"
```

If your goal is to remove all the nodes in the NodeSet, instead of searching through that list you can simply use:

```
divs.remove
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     
# >>     
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

When I'm deleting nodes I don't gather an intermediate NodeSet, instead I do it on the fly using something like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"><p>foo</p></div>
    <div id="bar"><p>bar</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('div#bar p').remove

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <div id="foo"><p>foo</p></div>
# >>     <div id="bar"></div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

which deletes the embedded `<p>` tag in `#bar`. By relaxing the selector and changing from `at` to `search` I can remove them en masse:

```
doc.search('div p').remove

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <div id="foo"></div>
# >>     <div id="bar"></div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

If you *insist* on walking through the NodeSet, remember that they are like arrays, and you can treat them as such. Here's an example of using `reject` to skip a particular node:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"><p>foo</p></div>
    <div id="bar"><p>bar</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

divs = doc.search('div').reject{ |d| d['id'] == 'foo' }
divs.map(&:to_html) # => ["<div id=\"bar\"><p>bar</p></div>"]
```

You won't receive a NodeSet though, you'll get an Array:

```
divs.class # => Array
```

While you can do that, you're better off using a specific selector to reduce the set rather than rely on Ruby to `select` or `reject` elements.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for that explanation and guidance.  I mistakenly thought that a Nodeset was like a separate array that I could delete items from without affecting the document.  I have a much better understanding now.